# Adding extras to a reservation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a reservation application which allows you to reserve a vehicle. I've got this working fine and without overlapping reservations. I would like my application to ask the user if they would like to add any extras. I've already created a extra table which lists all the extras available. I understand I will need a table which is in between them both reservationextra (something along those lines) as the relationship will be many to many.

I need some ideas of how I'm going to implement this. One idea I have is once the user reserves the vehicle it redirects the user to the "reservationextra" bit where the reservation_id is passed as a parameter and the user selects all the extras they require (can be multiple). The only thing is I'm not too sure how I'm going to implement this as I'm quite new to RubyonRails and still learning.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Edit ---

I've now made a page where the reservation id is passed and shown on reservation extra page.

I've managed to list all the extras in the reservation extra page.

views:

```
  <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :reservation_id %>
   <%= form.text_field :reservation_id, id: :reservationextra_reservation_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :extra_id %>
   <%= form.text_field :extra_id, id: :reservationextra_extra_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="row" >
   <% @extras.each do |extra|  %>
   <div class="col-lg-4" align="center">
     <%= extra.item %>
     <div id="img-box">
       <% if not extra.image.blank? %>
         <%= image_tag extra.image, :size => "200x200" %>
       <% else %>
         <%= image_tag "no-image.jpg", :size => "200x200" %>
       <% end %>
     </div>
     £<%= extra.price %>
     </br>
   </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
   <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

controller:

```
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @reservationextra = Reservationextra.new
    @reservationextra.reservation_id = @reservation.id
    @extras = Extra.all
  end
```

How would I get it so if the user wants to add an they can select all the ones they want i.e. 1 or all depending on what the user wants.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

for each .rb I've set up the 1 to m relationship

Comment: You probably want to create a set of ReservationExtras for each Reservation when it's initialized, then use `form.nested_attributes_for` in your form to present a check box for each one. `has_and_belongs_to_many` might be a bit misleading here, because it assumes you only have two columns in the table, and you want at least one more, which is saying "do I want this?"

Comment: Your question is very basic. You'll get better answers if you do some research and then post some ideas, showing your code. I recommend you research `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships for Rails and then decide how your models fit into those relationships. Since you don't reveal your models or any code it is difficult to provide a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update question once I get something together

Comment: please see edit.